# How can I fetch records based on String comparison in where clause. NOTE : String may contain special characters

Tags: java, postgresql, spring-boot

Running the following native query in a loop. It works fine till the String gets a name which contains special characters.

```
Select *
from Table 
where name like '"+name+"'
```

It Works fine when name is like `"Papa John"`
But exception is thrown when name contains a apostrophe and its like  `"Papa's Den"`

Postgresql treats it like 'Papa' and the rest of the chars aren't in  **' '** .

I have tried the following:

Just so my String could get accepted by postgresql by looking like this `"Papa\''s Den"` .

```
if name.contains("'"){
   name.replace("'","\\''")
}
```

But the above doesn't provide the desired transformed String.
Any different approach or correction in the current one would be appreciated.

Comment: Learn about prepared statements

Comment: I am on it. Hope the issue gets resolved by using prepared statements. Thanks @Jens

Answer (score 0):

You can use the regular expressions on PostgreSQL. Regular expression gives you the ability to remove other characters from a string, remove only numbers, or remove only alphabetic characters and PostgreSQL has many functions for regular expressions. For example, I use `regexp_replace` function.

Examples:

```
SELECT regexp_replace('Jons+=@$) Smith', '[^\w]+', ',', 'g');
-- Result: Jons,Smith
```

we can replace other symbols to ',' symbol, or we can only remove too, not replace

```
SELECT regexp_replace('Jons+=@$) Smith', '[^\w]+', '', 'g');
-- Result: JonsSmith
```

I do not fully understand how you need a search, that I will give as additional information. If you will replace other symbols with ',' then using the string_to_array and unnest functions you can convert all words in the string to rows (same as that table records)
Example:

```
SELECT unnest(string_to_array(regexp_replace('Jon!@#$ Sarah &*&Tom', '[^\w]+', ',', 'g'), ','))
```

Result:

| Column1 |
| --- |
| Jon |
| Sarah |
| Tom |

You can use this result in queries, for example `select * from table1 where first_name IN ()` or you can join this select result with other tables.